# Detect which character was backspaced in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to detect whenever the user backspaces the `@` key. The code I'm using is:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let  char = string.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
            print("Backspace was pressed")

        }
        return true
    }
```

..but it doesn't tell me which key was backspaced. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backspace doesn't show up in the `replacementString` argument. The system implements backspace by specifying a range to delete (which will span a single composed character sequence unless the user has selected a range of text), with a replacement string of `""` (the empty string). So to detect a backspace or other delete action:

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string == "" && range.length > 0 {
            // Backspace or other deletion
            let stringToDelete = (textField.text! as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
            if stringToDelete == "@" {
                print("bye-bye @")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```